# There was an error running the selected code generator 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'ERP.EF.StockItem' Ambiguous match found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to compile a controller and I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator 'Unable to retrieve
>   metadata for 'ERP.EF.StockItem' Ambiguous match found

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the same namespace for 2 different StockItem classes.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party but this was happening to me because I had the same property with different types in the parent and child classes